# BeautifulSoup won't display description text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, I was starting a project where I would scrape 'https://www.gumtree.com/cars/uk' and extract all used cars prices and experiment with machine learning algorithms on those data. However, when I use requests api alongside beautiful soup to extract the html files, I realised that it won't display the description text of the website.

Here's an example:
[image]

Here's the beautiful soup result:
[image]
As you can see instead of getting the description of the car, I got something like 'amp;lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&lhblk;&'.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Here's my code till now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import json

cars = requests.get('https://www.gumtree.com/cars/uk','lxml')
soup = bs(cars.content)

match = soup.find('div',class_ = 'srp-results') #div with an id of class srp_container-main. We are getting the div
#with an information of that class
print(match)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things, the site you mention is dynamic, there there is part of the content that will be modified by script I guess (I didn't open it). Other times you may be blocked. Here is an example code. By the content I saw, I would select 'p.listing-description' instead, also I excluded from the text strings that have number of distinct characters <=10.

```py
descrs = []
for p in soup.find_all('p', class_='listing-description'):
    if len(set(p.text)) > 10:
        descrs.append(p.text)
        print('-' * 80)
        print(p.text)
```

This shows you what it finds and gives a list with the texts of each node.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this myself, using the site you provided, I clicked on a car, looked up the description that I want to parse and did the following;

```
import bs4
import requests


cars = requests.get("https://www.gumtree.com/p/bmw/2009-bmw-3-series-3.0-330i-m-sport-2dr-convertible-petrol-automatic/1396099352")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(cars.text, "html.parser") 

match = soup.select('#is-being-refined > div.is-being-refined-hide.letterbox > div > div.grid-container.main > main > div.grid-col-m-6.grid-col-l-8 > div:nth-child(1) > section.grid-col-12 > p.ad-description') #div with an id of class srp_container-main. We are getting the div
result = match[0].text.strip()
print(result)
```

I right clicked the CSS element I wanted to parse and selected "Copy CSS
selector" ( this was done in Chrome )

My result:

" We are very proud to present this  Central Door Locking,..........Airbag; Full Service History; CD Player; Alarm; Safety Belt Pretensioners; Xenon headlights; Electric Windows; Leather Seats; AM/FM Stereo; Cruise Control; Driver Airbag; Power-assisted"

It parsed the text, stripped the white space and new line characters and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I just realised that when I single out a post and try to extract the text, I can actually do it but when it comes to extracting text from here : 'https://www.gumtree.com/cars/uk'. It doesn't work

Comment: I assume the issue lies there, since your program does not navigate through the site, meaning that it probably can not find the CSS selector you want to extract. 

I suggest that you look into the Selenium Module, that lets you control the browser. Best of luck